# Primefaces - input Text: How to change input text

Tags: primefaces, user-input

I have an input Text with a relating validator, so only whole numbers are allowed incl. "-1" (for infinity).
If I have a -1 I can map this to a (userfriendly) text with

```
<h:outputText value="#{object.quantity == '-1' ? 'infinity' : object.quantity}"/>
```

The input field looks like this:

```
<p:inputText id="quantityInput" value="#{object.quantity}" />
```

Question: How can I display "infinity" if a user types a "-1"?

TY

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can solve your problem this way:

```
 <h:outputText id="something" value="#{object.quantity == '-1' ? 'infinity' : object.quantity}"/>

 <p:inputText id="quantityInput" value="#{object.quantity}" >
        <f:ajax event="blur" update="something"  />
    </p:inputText>
```

Define an ID to your `h:outputText` and use an Ajax function to update your `h:outputText`.

You can see more in [Primefaces Showcase - Ajax Framework Events](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml)

PS: `blur` is an Ajax event, you can change to other if you want!